# Extra space is coming in html output

Tags: html, css

here i am pasting html & css and when UI comes then extra space was coming. just could not understand why it is coming and how to make it look proper.

### HTML

```
<div style="display: block; z-index: 1001; outline: 0px none; height: 400px; width: 400px; top: 77px; left: 428px;" class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all noTitleStuff ui-draggable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-dialog2"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix"><span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-dialog2">&nbsp;</span><a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a></div><div id="dialog2" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: auto;">
    <div id="Container">
    <div id="acloginpod">
                    <div id="caption">&nbsp;Enter Login Information&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="acloginform">
                        <fieldset>
                            <span id="ctl00_mstPartBase_rptlogin_ctl00_Label1">Email Address:</span>
                            <input type="text" name="ctl00$mstPartBase$rptlogin$ctl00$txtEmail" id="ctl00_mstPartBase_rptlogin_ctl00_txtEmail" tabindex="1" class="textinput">
                            <span id="ctl00_mstPartBase_rptlogin_ctl00_Label2">Password:</span>
                            <input type="password" name="ctl00$mstPartBase$rptlogin$ctl00$txtPassword" id="ctl00_mstPartBase_rptlogin_ctl00_txtPassword" tabindex="2" class="textinput">
                            <div class="aclogin-action">
                                <div class="fl-left">
                                    <div class="item">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="ctl00_mstPartBase_rptlogin_ctl00_chkRemember" name="ctl00$mstPartBase$rptlogin$ctl00$chkRemember" tabindex="3">
                                        Remember me
                                    </label>
                                    </div>

                                    <a id="ctl00_mstPartBase_rptlogin_ctl00_LinkButton1" tabindex="5" class="forgotpass" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$mstPartBase$rptlogin$ctl00$LinkButton1','')">Forgot password?</a>
                                </div>
                                <div id="btn" style="float:right;">
                                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$mstPartBase$rptlogin$ctl00$btnLogin" value="Login" id="ctl00_mstPartBase_rptlogin_ctl00_btnLogin" class="btnlogin" de="" style="margin-left: 83px">
                                <input type="submit" name="ctl00$mstPartBase$rptlogin$ctl00$btnRegister" value="Register" id="ctl00_mstPartBase_rptlogin_ctl00_btnRegister" class="btnlogin">
                                     </div>
                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    &nbsp;</div>
                                <br>

                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

### CSS

```
#acloginpod {
    background: url("../Images/acloginpodbg.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #ebebeb;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#acloginpod label {
    color: #444;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

#caption {
    background: url("../Images/button-background-1.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #1db74b;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: White;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 1px #000;
}

.btnlogin {
    background: url("../Images/button-background-1.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #1db74b;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #333;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 33px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 1px #000;
}
.btnlogin:hover {
    background: url("../Images/button-background-2.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #046629 inset;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 3px #333;
}
.btnlogin:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
}


#acloginpod input.textinput {
    background: url("../Images/textinputbg.gif") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 7px 0;
    text-indent: 7px;
    width: 100%;
}

#acloginpod .acloginform {
    margin: 22px;
}

#acloginpod form, #acloginpod fieldset {
    border-width: 0;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

also here i am pasting screen shot.

[image]

extra space is coming between two div called `dialog2 & container` so just guide me which css i need to modify as a result extra space will not come in left,right,top & bottom side. thanks

here is the js fiddle demo of my code **http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/jj2cM/**

### here is my full code which is working

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" />

    <style type="text/css">
    .noTitleStuff .ui-dialog-titlebar {display:none}
    .offscreen {position: absolute; left: -999em;}
    .BusyStyles
         {
             background-image: url('../Images/ajax-loader.gif');
             background-repeat: no-repeat;
             background-position: center center;
             height: 350px;
             width: 300px;
         }

    .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content{
        padding:0 !important;    
    }
    </style>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#opener2").click(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.toggleClass('show');

            if ($this.hasClass('show')) {

                $("<div id='dialog2'/>").dialog(
                {
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 50,
                    height: 50,
                    dialogClass: 'noTitleStuff',
                    draggable: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).dialog("widget").addClass('BusyStyles');
                        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
                    }
                }).dialog('open').show()
                .load('login.aspx', function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
                    if (statusTxt == "success") {
                        //alert('data found');
//                        sHtml = responseTxt;
//                        var element = $(this).find('#Container'); ;
//                        //$(element).addClass('offscreen').show();
//                        var width = element.width();
//                        var height = element.height();
//                        //alert('h ' + height + ' w ' + width);

//                        sHtml = $(sHtml).find('#Container').html();
//                        $sHtml = $(sHtml)
//                        $sHtml.css({ 'display': 'none' }).appendTo('div#dialog2');


                        $(this).dialog("widget").removeClass('BusyStyles');
                        $("#dialog2").dialog("widget").animate({
                            width: '346px',
                            height: 'auto'
                        }, {
                            duration: 200,
                            step: function () {
                                $("#dialog2").dialog('option', 'position', 'center');
                            }
                        });

                        $("#dialog2").css({ height: 'auto', width: 'auto' });
                        //$("#dialog2").html(sHtml);

                    }

                    if (statusTxt == "error") {
                        alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
                    }

                });

                //$("#dialog2").dialog('open').show();


            }
            else {
                $("#dialog2").dialog("close").dialog('destroy').remove();
            }
            return false;
        });

    });


</script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <button id="opener2">open the dialog2</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you got the js that opens the dialogue? if it is jqueryui's dialogue you should be able to set the width and height so there is no space: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: i did that but no luck

Comment: from http://jsfiddle.net/KAz2J/ I don't see any space. container is a child of dialog2, can you be more explicit about what space you are talking?

Comment: which browser you are testing? I didn't see any extra space coming between two div called dialog2 & container.

Comment: the demo of my code from jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/jj2cM/

Comment: i am testing in firefox.

Comment: I still don't see any extra space between two div called dialog2 & container. I have latest version of firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to set `padding:0` to this class:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content{
    padding:0 !important;    
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVLN6/9/)